# Adding URL redirect to Button Group Buttons

Tags: html, css, redirect, hyperlink

I was able to create a horizontal button group using CSS. My button group was designed very similar to what's found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_group.asp).

I have been searching and trying various methods to essentially make these buttons clickable links that will redirect to another page, each with its own URL, for example. However, I have not found a solution that works.

How can the buttons in the group be made into clickable links or otherwise redirect to another page/site when clicked?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) change button with links and apply the same style 2) use js and click event

Comment: please post minimal example code, to make it easier for others to help you

Answer (score 0):

```css
.btn-group {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green background */
    border: 1px solid green; /* Green border */
    color: white; /* White text */
    padding: 10px 24px; /* Some padding */
    cursor: pointer; /* Pointer/hand icon */
    float: left; /* Float the buttons side by side */
    text-decoration: none;
}


.btn-group a:not(:last-child) {
    border-right: none; /* Prevent double borders */
}

/* Add a background color on hover */
.btn-group:hover {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<h1>Button Group</h1>

<div>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><button class="btn-group">Apple</button></a>
  <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank"><button class="btn-group">Samsung</button></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<button>` elements are not intended to have an "href" attribute. To achieve this, you could use an `<a>` tag with an "href" attribute, and style this to appear similar to your button

For example:

```css
div.container {
    padding: 10px;
}

a.button {
    color: #2196f3;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #2196f3;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s; /* safari */
    -moz-transition: all .3s; /* mozilla */
    -ms-transition: all .3s; /* IE */
    -o-transition: all .3s; /* opera */
}

a.button:hover,
a.button:focus,
a.button:active {
    background-color: #2196f3;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <a href="#" class="button">Styled Anchor Button</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! How would an <a> tag with an "href" attribute be formatted?

Comment: I added an example for you, check it!

Comment: @ gabriele-giudice Thank you! How might I organize, say 4 of those buttons, together, horizontally, to span a page? I would like to mimic the appearance of the horizontal buttons here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_button_group.asp

Comment: I modified the above snippet to make button look better :D
One moment, I'll do a codepen for you

Comment: This is how to make justified buttons: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qxYKMG
They could be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, n buttons, they will always span the entire parent width. Learn how to use flexboxes, they are very important for responsive web pages

Comment: Thank you so much for your help & time! I will study up on flexboxes and will be playing around with colors and fonts, etc., for the buttons. I really appreciate your responding. :)

Comment: No problem, everybody needs a little help :)